# Looping through two arrays and adding the collection of each into new array without dups

Tags: python, django, algorithm

I have two arrays that I want to loop through. Array A and Array B. I want to add the elements of both array into a new Array that contains the collection of all elements in that array without any duplication. This will be written in python.

```
For Example
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [1,5,6,7]
Collection = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I was wondering if there's a faster and more efficient to do it without looping through each indexes and comparing it and then storing it. Because that's what I'm planning to do but I think it will take really long time given that I have about a couple thousand elements in each array.

Comment: `Collection = list(set(A+B))`

Comment: `collection = {*A, *B}`

Answer (score 2):

There is, using `set`:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [1,5,6,7]
C = set(A + B)
```

If you want `C` to be a list instead, simply convert it back afterwards:

```
C = list(set(A + B))
```

Comment: how would you convert it back afterwards ?

Comment: @VathanaHim using `list()`, like in my last line.

Comment: this would not include any duplicates right ?

Comment: @VathanaHim Yes, that is what `set` does, removes duplicates.

Comment: ok sweet i'm new to python so idk but thanks :)

Comment: @VathanaHim How are you combining the lists?  My code as is should work fine.

Comment: nevermind it was some syntax error